# Closing posts by people that lack required prerequisite knowledge?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Philosophy Stack Exchange post: [Philosophy of Logic – Converting formal proofs to sound deductive inference](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61999/philosophy-of-logic-converting-formal-proofs-to-sound-deductive-inference)

What policy or guidance prevents people from closing posts as unclear that are unclear only  because the person closing the post lacks the required prerequisite knowledge?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Closing posts as unclear (that are perfectly clear) seems to be a way around that fact that there is no button to close a post for breaking the non existent rule that peer reviews are not allowed. This really seems to be far less than fully forthcoming and thus a serious breach of professional decorum.

If there is no rule saying peer reviews are not allowed, and there is no button that allows closing a post for breaking the rule that peer reviews are not allowed then the honest approach would seem to refrain from closing such posts. The approach currently being employed seems unethical.

**This assumes that the peer review question fits the Q&A model in that this question is focused on a single point having a precise objective answer.**

Comment: it's a "moral" clique, not a community. don't sweat it so

Comment: @another_name  My future depends upon making these points understood. This is not some little hobbyist sideline for me.

Comment: then you should have a tutor that can help.

Comment: @another_name The only tutor that could possibly help is other PhD's that have already published in the field. I only found one guy in the last 22 years that ever said much more than blah blah blah you are wrong because I really believe that you are wrong and he was here on SE. My presentation has improved a lot in the last 22 years, and especially in the last two weeks.

Comment: Why does your future depends upon making these points understood?

Comment: @ PhilipKlöcking Although the question may be somewhat of a duplicate I had to ask it again because I only got dodges rather than answers. The answer that I cobbled together is that posts are closed as unclear that are perfectly clear. They are closed for breaking the non-existent rule that asking for peer review is forbidden when there is no such rule at all. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 7):

If your question is unclear to the community of Philosophy.SE users then it's sufficient reason for closure. The burden is on you to make it clear, not on us to figure out what you mean.

But the real problem with your post (and your previous ones) is that you're not really asking a question. You're posting original work, but this is not the place for that.

Comment: So if I really did come up with something very significant it would be impossible to get sufficient peer review to make my words clear enough to be understood to get published.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT This site isn't a proof reading service if that's what you're after. If you want peer review then submit a paper to a journal.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not talking about proof reading. I have tried submitting to journals after six months the only feedback that I got was no thanks we are not interested. I am right on the verge of saying it clearly enough to be understood. A SE member acknowledged that he both understood and agreed that the first half of my idea is correct. He agreed that I have correctly translated conventional valid deduction to its formal proof equivalent. The next half is doing this same thing for sound deduction.

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't possibly make any progress on this unless I get feedback on whether or not what I am saying is understood. I have always totally understood everything that I have said and it seems quite baffling that others do not.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT Submit to another journal? Enrol in a university's philosophy program?

Comment: @curiousdannii Since I had to wait 6 months for zero success how does it make sense? I need constant and feedback several times a day from someone that understands this material for two weeks. Call that 84 feedbacks. Going the journal route (if they provide any feedback) would take 42 years. Most philosophy programs are clueless about mathematical logic.

Comment: @curiousdannii In any case no one addressed my primary question. How can we avoid closing posts that are only not clear enough because the one that is doing the closing simply does not have the required prerequisite background?

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT If there aren't 5 users (out of our 28 thousand!) who do have the prerequisite background knowledge who could reopen the question, then the reality is the question probably shouldn't be reopened. Because you can be sure there'll be more than enough people with no idea who would write answers anyway if it were open.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I am only asking that people that have no idea what I am talking about only because they don't know the subject material should not be allowed to decide whether or not these questions are clear enough. If you don't totally understand formal proofs of mathematical logic then you don't get to vote on the clarity these questions. What keeps high school students from voting against brain surgeons? There really should be something.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT That something is people who do know about the subject matter and can reopen the question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Getting people that don't know about the subject to quit deleting my posts would  be good enough.  Each total rewrite gets clearer and clearer. None of this can ever possibly be clear enough for people that do not know formal proofs of mathematical logic very well because that is the subject. There should be a rule that you don't get to vote against any post that you don't know the subject matter.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT How do you propose to prevent cranks coming along and declaring we just don't understand their new philosophies well enough and therefore can't close their questions?

Comment: @curiousdannii There would be a simple self-enforced guideline. If you know that you don't know very much about formal proofs then you know that you are not supposed to vote on the clarity of of posts where the subject matter is formal proofs. Other moderators could help enforce this. If they continue to see someone voting down posts that they know nothing about, they report this person.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT You don't need any background in mathematics nor philosophy to see that you failed do ask a question. There is a close reason "push of personal philosophy" which states that questions that do not really ask anything beyond "am I right" or "what do you say" are supposed to be closed because they are off-topic. In other words: StackExchange is not the right place to serve your needs. The users acted correctly and there is no need for such a rule.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking It is still dishonest to say that a math proof question is off topic in a math group. Instead the message should be: "We are playing jeopardy here, even though your material is totally on topic, your answers must be phrased as a question".

Comment: @PL_OLCOTTp A question can be off-topic here both because of not being about philosophy and because of not being about what StackExchange is about. There is nothing dishonest in saying that the latter is the case here.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT Our reply to you is similar to the one you got from journals: No, thank you.

Comment: @Eliran That sort of reply is very rude.

Comment: @PL_OLCOOT as far as I know, participating here doesn't even count as "service to the profession or community at large" for most of us who do have PhDs. This a completely *voluntary* thing for everyone involved. We have no obligation to help you sort out your novel proof. / In short, this isn't the right venue to get that sort of help.

Comment: @virmaior This is the ONLY venue available, and it may take as little as a few more minutes to validate my system and what it achieves. This requires someone that is very familiar with formal proofs of mathematical logic. Hardly any PhD's have that. The foundation of math stuff is apparently already considered a done deal, thus not worth hardly anyone's time. I really don't think that it is too much to ask for people that do not know this subject to refrain from voting my posts to deletion.

Comment: *Absurd*. There's plenty of other venues available. (1) You can e-mail faculty who work in the area you are in. (2) You can write a blog. (3) You can post on reddit. (4) you can hire a tutor. / you're confusing a SE called philosophy with a one-stop shop for anything you want related to philosophy.

Comment: @virmaior I can't hire a PhD with significant publications in the field of formal proofs of mathematical logic. I have tried writing to PhD's before my material was fully vetted, it didn't work. Reddit is no good. My Blog has been helpful, yet only after I find people that know this material.

Comment: I think you'd be surprised at how cheaply you could hire a PhD. Someone did it for $1000. (http://steve-patterson.com/responding-jason-brennans-review-square-one/)

Comment: @Eliran you just admitted in my "duplicate" question that it is not really about clarity at all. You call a post unclear as an excuse to close it knowing full well that it is not unclear. I spent about 100 hours trying to make my post clear enough.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT: The close reason that is given is that which most of the voters gave. And it is perfectly ok to say "unclear what you are **asking**". It is not about the content being unclear, but there being no question. And even **if** the close reason itself wasn't the most appropriate one, this would not make it worth reopening, since as pointed out often enough, there are other valid reasons to keep it closed.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking What I am asking is clear. I am asking for academic peer review of my process for defining: "deductively sound formal proofs of mathematical logic". So if the post is clear, the question is clear and academic peer review is not explicitly forbidden then my post should have never been closed.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT "I **ask for** peer review" is not the same as **asking a question**. The purpose of StackExchange is creating a knowledge database on diverse subjects in a Q&A format. Peer review does not have this format, hence it's off topic. There is no point in discussing this, it is obvious for everyone but you, who probably does understand it, but refuses to accept it because of your needs standing in the way. I am sympathetic with that, but this is not the place for peer review.

Answer (score 2):

Members are permitted to cast close votes if they have a reputation of 500 or more. There are no other requirements.  Here is the privilege page for other available privileges and the required reputation:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

As an alternative to asking questions what you might do is read the questions and answers tagged with topics you are interested in. This will give you a feel for what kind of questions people here are able to answer. Perhaps you can answer some of the questions yourself. Perhaps they will suggest specific questions you might ask.

Comment: I need a very specific question answered that has never been asked. What would solve my problem with this is that all of the people that do not know the subject material would not be allowed to vote that it is unclear when it is only unclear because they don't know the subject material.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT There is a good chance that no one here knows the answer to the question. I don't know the answer. That is why I am suggesting an indirect approach that involves looking at related questions and answers.

Comment: Alternatively people that have no idea what I am talking about could quit voting my posts to deletion so that someone that does know the subject matter could eventually respond

Comment: "Members are permitted to cast close votes if they have a reputation of 500 or more. There are no other requirements."  I think that telling the truth would be a requirement. If a member votes to close for clarity and it does not really have a clarity problem they would be fibbing. This is an ethical violation on their part.